# Oracle client not connecting to Oracle server (separate docker containers)

Tags: oracle, docker-container, tnsnames, oracleclient

My problem is that I'm not able to connect to my Oracle Database (version 21.3.0 running in one docker container) from my Oracle client (version 21 running in a separate docker container).

Here is the context of the execution.

On my computer (host) I'm on windows. From my windows I run a linux virutal machine (through virtual-box) which I use to run my docker containers (it's a personal development environment).

I built the 2 docker images my self following the official instructions from here https://github.com/oracle/docker-images. Used the OracleDatabase subdirectory (version 21.3.0) and the OracleInstantClient/oraclelinux7 (version 21). (Installation binaries are downloaded during the image build from official repos).

To run my Oracle Database server I use this command line :

`docker run -dti --network=sai -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_PWD=password123 --name=oracle-xe oracle/database:21.3.0-xe`

I've created the user-defined network "sai" so that both containers can see each other.

For the client I've used this tnsnames.ora in default directory /usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/network/admin/ :

```
XE =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle-xe)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SID = XE)
            (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
        )
    )
```

Here is my command line to run  the client :
`docker run -ti --network=sai --rm oracle-instantclient bash`
If I install ping utility in my client container I can ping oracle-xe and it's responding.

when I run sqlplus and after entering username/password I got this message :
`ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified`

I've added trace and here is the content sqlnet.log

```
2022-12-07T11:22:53.330824+00:00
Create Relation ADR_CONTROL
Create Relation ADR_INVALIDATION
Create Relation INC_METER_IMPT_DEF
Create Relation INC_METER_PK_IMPTS
```

After some research, it appeared that it was because the ORACLE_SID variable was not set. I tried first to add it in the tnsnames.ora (as you can see) but it didn't change anything so I tried using the following command:
`export ORACLE_SID=XE`

Now I get another error :
`ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`

and now this is the content of the sqlnet.log file:

```
2022-12-07T11:28:22.644437+00:00
***********************************************************************
Fatal NI connect error 12545, connecting to:
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)(PROGRAM=/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/bin/oracle)(ARGV0=oracleXE)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))')(DETACH=NO))(CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus)(HOST=c09ab9b0630a)(USER=root))(CONNECTION_ID=7zw32Sp/AAfgUwMAEqxRbQ==)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
        TNS for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
        Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
  Version 21.8.0.0.0
  Time: 07-DEC-2022 11:28:22
  Tracing to file: /root/oradiag_root/diag/clients/user_root/host_3819129240_110/trace/ora_7_140531135179328.trc
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12545

TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 515

TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
    nt secondary err code: 2
    nt OS err code: 0
```

What is weird in that trace is that HOST=c09ab9b0630a is actually my client container (not my database container oracle-xe) and it is confirmed (I think) by the LOCAL=YES. It's like my tnsnames.ora isn't taken into account. I tried also to set the variable TNS_ADMIN but it doesn't change anything.

What makes me think the problem is a configuration problem in the client container is that I can connect to my database container from my sql developer on my Windows (host). To succeed that, I forwarded my port 1521 to my virtual machine, I used the -p option on my database container and I setup the tnsnames.ora on windows as the following :

```
XE =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
        )
    )
```

That is working fine.

In the Client container :

I tried to change the values in the tnsnames.ora by putting the real name of the container or the ip of my host (with the -p option server side).

I tried removing the -p option when running the database container.

In all those cases I got the same errors.

Reading the sqlnet.log file I feel like the tnsnames.ora is not taken into account and so it's looking to the wrong place. But I'm not oracle expert.

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**

The problem is definitely with the tnsnames.ora on the client side because when I use the following command in my client container it works :

sqlplus userName/password@oracle-xe/XE

But I really need to figure out that tnsnames.ora problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who would like the answer... The problem was that you can't ommit the connect string when using sqlplus. So at least provide the TNS entry like this :

`sqlplus username/password@XE`

this works fine.

Best Regards

Comment: When the Oracle Client libraries used by the application binary (e.g. SQL\*Plus) are not the exact same libraries as used by the DB binaries, then you need to specify a connection string.  Since your DB is on a different host you need to specify the connection string.